# Scikit-learn Nearest Neighbor search with weighted distance metric

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance, nearest-neighbor, weighted

Trying to use minkowski distance and pass weights but the sklearn metrics do not allow this. Tried pdist and cdist from scipy but these calculate the distances before hand!

```
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

        X = pd.read_csv('.file.csv')

        weights = [1] * X.shape[1] # filled with 1's for now

        nbrs = NearestNeighbors(
                                algorithm = 'brute',
                                metric = minkowski(u, v, p=1, w=weights), n_jobs = -1)
                               .fit(X)

    distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X=X, n_neighbors=50, return_distance=True)
```

This returns:

```
"NameError: name 'u' is not defined"
```

`callable(minkowski)` returns True!

I know I'm not passing u and v so unsurprisingly the error shows up. The documentation for this is a bit poor for using other metrics outside from those supported in sklearn. How can I use a weighted metric from scipy for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are trying to include the weights is your problem. As `u` and `v` are not defined and are internally passed to the metric callable you shouldn't actually include them in your code. You should create a partial function with [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)from `minkowski` with the values of `p` and `w` predefined.

```
from functools import partial

w_minkowski = partial(minkowski, p=1, w=weights)
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(algorithm='brute', metric=w_minkowski, n_jobs=-1)
nbrs.fit(X)
...
```

Comment: This did the trick alright. Compared to pdist (scipy) this method uses all available CPU power. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can now use the `'wminkowski'` metric and pass the weights to the metric using `metric_params`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

seed = np.random.seed(9)
X = np.random.rand(100, 5)
weights = np.random.choice(5, 5, replace=False)

nbrs = NearestNeighbors(algorithm='brute',
                        metric='wminkowski',
                        metric_params={'w': weights},
                        p=1,
                        n_jobs=-1)
nbrs.fit(X)
```

Output:

```
NearestNeighbors(algorithm='brute', leaf_size=30, metric='wminkowski',
                 metric_params={'w': array([2, 0, 3, 4, 1])}, n_jobs=-1,
                 n_neighbors=5, p=1, radius=1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Minkowski distance for `p=1` you can just set `NearestNeighbors` `metric` parameter to `'manhattan'` or `'l1'` (these are strings). You could also set `metric` to `'minkowski'` and set `p` parameter accordingly.

For details see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors)